# Video is 25fps, audio 50 fps?

Tags: audio, frame-rate

In my country we ever use the 25fps(PAL) for video, and for audio.
Yesterday I record a tv movie with vdr(mpeg-ts format) and mediainfo report this for audio and video
Audio is mp2, video h264

Audio

```
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 2
Codec ID                                 : 4
Duration                                 : 3 h 58 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 41.667 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -406 ms
Stream size                              : 219 MiB (6%)
```

Video

```
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Format settings, picture structure       : Frame
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 3 h 58 min
Bit rate                                 : 1 915 kb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
```

How is possible audio/video are in sync with a FPS of about 50fps on audio?
If I want to recode it, I have to recode audio on 25fps?

Comment: You mean the field on audio that says "41.667 FPS" ?  What tool did  you use to generate this dump?  There's no concept of frames per second for audio (think about it).  My guess is that this is a placeholder value.  Otherwise, it's not very meaningful for any scenario.

Comment: Also, mp3 is a series of "frames" - where each frame is a unique header followed by a series of encoded samples.  That's where the frames/second might be coming from. But it won't be relevant to your video frames/second.  Different terminology for "frame". http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html

Comment: The tool is mediainfo, reported on question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: You don't have to worry about it.  Two different meanings for "frames per second".

MP3 is an interesting file format.  It doesn't have a global header that represents the entire file.  Instead MP3 is a concatenation of small individual files called "frames".  Each frame is a few milliseconds in length.  That's why you can often just chop an MP3 file in half and the second half plays just fine.  It's what also enables VB3 MP3 to exist. The sample rate or encoding parameters can change at any point in the file.

So your particular MP3 has a "frame rate" of 41.667 frames per second.   Now notice the SPF value of 1152 in parentheses.  That's "samples per frame".  If you do the math: `1152 samples/frame` * 41.667 frames/second` is almost exactly 48000 samples per second.  Identical to the sampling rate presented by the mediainfo tool.

When a media player plays a video file, it will basically render the video stream separate from the audio stream, so there's very little effort it needs to keep the different sample rates in sync.

As to your question about resampling for video.  The encoding tool you use will do the right thing.  The FPS for MP3 is completely orthogonal to the video FPS.

Comment: Oh yeah - "layer" is also an overloaded term in the mpeg world.  An MP3 file could contain layer 2 codec.   But you get the idea.